# flex-box stretching issue

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a problem with flex-box. I want a one column with two rows where there are 2 columns on the second row. However I want to use just one wrapper element for it (I do not want to wrap the second row into a div). The issue is that I want only the second row elements to strech.

Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/x8g0wupg/

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
  <header>text</header>
  <div id="a">text</div>
  <div id="b">text</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

header {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50px;
  flex: 1 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

#a {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#b {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I managed to make them the way I want them to be positioned however the first column element just doesnt want to shring to the height I have set to him instead of it it leaves a empty space to the vertical 50% of the wrapper.

Is there any way to do it without extra wrapper for the second row?

Thank you!

Comment: Not without magic numbers...that's not the way flexbox works natively.

Comment: @Paulie_D Oh okay, thats what i wanted to know. I am trying to figure it out for some time now and at least i know it is impossible now. Thank you

Comment: If the height of one inner element is known you could probably use `calc` but that's not a flexbox solution of course.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hackish, with `align-self: flex-end;` and a negative top margin on the parent.

See https://jsfiddle.net/C14L/1rj3kdkb/